# Alternative for window.location.href in react for a single-page-application

Tags: reactjs

I have two different react applications, one for customer and one for admin.
Customer app runs on port 3000 and admin on 3001.

I have a button where I want to change from the admin page to the customer page and vice versa.

For now, I am using window.location.href to reload to another url and this works, like this :

```
onClick={event =>  window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/customerloginpage'}
```

I tried redirect and routes and using history but what happens is that it adds the url to the end of the current url instead of replacing ,example :

```
 const history = useHistory();
  const customerButtonClicked = () =>{ 
    let path = 'http://localhost:3000/customerloginpage'; 
    history.push(path);
  }
```

Example result  :

```
'http://localhost:3001/adminloginpage/http://localhost:3000/customerloginpage'
```

Is there a way to do this without having to reload the page with window.location.href? Please explain this concept to me, thanks!

Comment: `history.push` will only work for cases where the new path belongs to the same domain as the current application. `window.location.href` is your best bet to switch between new domains